# Запустить программу на Python с GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu

Необходимо запустить скрипт на python3 с использованием видеокарты (это поможет значительно увеличить скорость работы, на CPU этот процесс занимает очень много времени). Задача в следующем: есть csv-файл, который содержит приблизительно 100 000 коротких текстов, каждый текст нужно разбить на биграммы (сочетания двух слов) и триграммы (сочетания трех слов), далее для всех биграмм и триграмм нужно посчитать delta tf-idf (метод, позволяющий определить эмоциональную окраску слова или словосочетания в численном виде) и вывести эту информацию в другой csv-файл. Искал информацию в интернете, наткнулся на такие библиотеки как numba и pycuda, но, если честно, не совсем понимаю, как можно их применить. Какие решения существуют?

Comment: `"Какие решения существуют?"` -- `"numba и pycuda"`. Вопрос закрыт? :D

Comment: Возможно и так, просто нужно разобраться как именно их применить

Comment: Скорее всего, numba может не подойти, так как, если правильно понимаю, она используется в основном как оптимизация для массивов numpy, а также накладывает строгие ограничения на написание функций

Comment: Как вы это делаете сейчас? Вы пробовали использовать Pandas + [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)?

Comment: @MaxU Насколько знаю, TfidfVectorizer использует не тот метод, который мне нужен, он занимается подсчетом tf-idf, а мне необходим именно Δtf-idf, который имеет другую формулу и применение

Comment: @ЯкимовГерман а как вы хотели? GPU - специализированное железо, обычную программу (предназначенную изначально для CPU) просто так как есть для GPU не скомпилируешь.

Comment: можно еще посмотреть [sklearn-deltatfidf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sklearn-deltatfidf)... Вопрос в том как ускорить ваш процесс или как заставить работать ваш код без изменений на GPU?

Comment: @MaxU Скорее моя задача в том, чтобы максимально ускорить процесс

Comment: Тогда имеет смысл переформулировать вопрос и добавить ["минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Советую также ознакомится с ["Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)."](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: @ЯкимовГерман, возможности оптимизации такие: оптимизация алгоритма -> распаралелить на ЦП -> переписать на Си -> профилировать пока не надоест -> попробовать перенести на GPU (cuda/openCL) (честно сказать, не сталкивался с обработкой текстов на GPU, думаю там будут свои подводные камни). Последнее практически наверняка потребует перенесение алгоритмов на Си-подобный язык.

Comment: Какие есть решения для параллельного распределения вычислений на ЦП? Для Python

Comment: Достаточные решения есть [из коробки][(https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrency.html). Скорей всего `multiprocessing`'а вполне хватит... но это уже отдельная тема более конкретных вопросов...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ускорить процесс и сэкономить память можно воспользоваться модулем [sklearn-deltatfidf](https://github.com/r-m-n/sklearn-deltatfidf).

Пример: давайте посчитаем `Delta TF-IDF` для всех биграмм из ["The 20 newsgroups text dataset"](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#the-20-newsgroups-text-dataset), который содержит 11.314 текстов в тренировочном наборе.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn_deltatfidf import DeltaTfidfVectorizer

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train')
# DeltaTfidfVectorizer expects labels (positive and negative values)
labels = np.where(newsgroups_train.target <= 5, 1, -1)

print(len(newsgroups_train.data))
#Output: 11314

dtfidf = DeltaTfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2))

X = dtfidf.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data, labels.tolist())
```

Результат: разреженная матрица размерности: `11314x1051696` с `2908623` ненулевых элементов:

```
In [58]: X
Out[58]:
<11314x1051696 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 2908623 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

использование памяти - 22MiB:

```
In [66]: X.data.nbytes / 1024**2
Out[66]: 22.19103240966797
```

при наивной реализации нам понадобилось бы ~44GiB для `np.float32`:

```
In [62]: 11314 * 1051696 * 4 / 1024**3
Out[62]: 44.32681405544281
```

или ~89GiB для `np.float64`:

```
In [63]: 11314 * 1051696 * 8 / 1024**3
Out[63]: 88.65362811088562
```

**Замер времени:**

```
In [59]: %timeit dtfidf.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data, labels.tolist())
18.3 s ± 1.13 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: А насколько быстрее стало? Можно в ответе пояснить: сколько было, сколько стало и т.п. :)

Comment: @gil9red, для этого надо увидеть код автора вопроса ([я попросил его опубликовать в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809903/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d1%81-gpu/810004?noredirect=1#comment1283485_809903)). По собственному опыту могу сказать, что `TfidfVectorizer` от которого унаследован `DeltaTfidfVectorizer` реализован очень грамотно и эффективно и быстро работает.

Comment: @gil9red, Например при наивной реализации приведенного выше примера для результирующей матрицы `X` понадобилось бы 44GiB - 88GiB памяти (`11314 * 1051696 * 4 / 1024**3` для `np.float32` или `11314 * 1051696 * 8 / 1024**3` для `np.float64`)